# Possible to build a coin that will never change it's code?

Tags: altcoin-development

I want to know if it's possible to create a coin that will never go through any kind of forks. Where there would be some kind of consequence for the majority of miners trying to change what it is. Is the only way to do this to make it not open source, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's trivially possible. All you have to do is never make any changes. Other people might make changes, but you are free to ignore them entirely if that's what you choose to do.

If the initial design is perfect, this should work out just fine. However, if there's anything wrong with the initial design at all or at some future point people consider it unsuitable, you will be stuck using a poor design. You might conceivably be the only person using that design, so it would cease to serve any purpose.

You will only be able to interoperate with people who believe as you do, of course. Just as they can't force you to change, you can't force them not to change.

But you could do it if that's what you really want to do. Nobody can force you to change things if you don't want to.

Comment: That could work too, while you're here how many lines of code do you think an insanely simple coin could be made in? Let me know if I should ask that in a new question.

Comment: It really depends what you're including in those lines of code. For example, if you're implementing a token with no special features on top of Ripple or Ethereum, almost no code at all is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by simple? If you mean "ignoring all possible incentive failures and attack vectors", probably just a few thousand. If you mean "without features beyond being a currency", Bitcoin is the best attempt and it's not anywhere near complete.

Comment: I mean something from scratch which has everything Bitcoin has

Comment: @Alanay Then the size of bitcoin core is a good guideline. That's about 60,000 lines of code just for the guts (not counting things like tests and a user interface).